# Complete exhaust system replacement necessary?

Tags: exhaust, acura

The car in question is a 2000 Acura TL, dual exhaust system.

One exhaust pipe of the dual system snapped off and is hanging down low.

I took the car in to two different mechanics, they both said something similar - that the entire system needs to be replaced, it can't be just a cut and weld job or anything like that.

One said the system had already been repaired via welding and that's part of the reason another cut/weld job wouldn't work.

If it matters, one quoted $1500 and one quoted $1300.

Does what they're saying make sense? I'm seeing very conflicting answers online about exhaust system replacements, and can't find that many threads about replacing the entire system.

Comment: I copied the text from the other question and added it in here. I believe this question is now on topic and reopened it as such.

Comment: Check your local craigslist/junk yard. These are fairly popular cars (depending on your location), and there's a decent chance somebody installed an aftermarket exhaust and is selling exactly what you're looking for. Check to see if your exhaust shop will install parts that you provide, but it should save you money vs getting an entirely new exhaust fabricated.

Comment: Internet websites (including this one) have a lot of good information, but cannot visually inspect your exhaust system like the shops you took it have. Knowing what they have to work with is how they determine if the whole system needs to be replaced. Keep in mind, they might actually be trying to save you the hassle of having to come back in a few months with it broken again.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the overall condition of the exhaust system and why it broke (and how much damage was done).

Assuming that the system is in generally good shape, and that the catalyst has life left in it, and the material can be welded reliably (some metals soften or harden as a result of the heat of the welding and need to be heat treated afterwards to restore the desired properties), then on the face of it, it doesn't seem unreasonable to weld it again, possibly replacing the damaged area(s).

Having said that, you need to find a shop that has the tools and skill to do it well. Get a quote form them and listen when they explain to you the pros and cons of repairing the existing exhaust.